# Is there a way to shorten Python for loops iterating over dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary

example:

```
dic = {'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}
for x, y in dic:
   print(x,y)
```

would ideally return

```
a b
```

but it throws an error instead. so, is there any alternative to doing this:

```
for x in dic:
    y = dic[x]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for x, y in dic.items():
   print(x, y)
```